# RSA keys do not have the same modulus

Tags: ssl-certificate, rsa, keystore

I created a rootKey.pem, client.key using openssl :

```
   $openssl genrsa -aes256  -out  client.key  2048

   $ sudo openssl req  -config openssl.cnf  -key  rootKey.pem   -new - 
    x509  -sha256  -extensions v3_ca   -out  root.crt  -days 3650

   $sudo openssl  x509  -req  -extfile openssl.cnf -extensions 
    v3_intermediate_ca  -CA root.crt  -CAkey  rootKey.pem  - 
    CAserial -days 1825   -in intermediateCsr.pem  -out 
                        intermediate.crt
```

I created a chain certificate (cat the ROOT cert+intermediate cert)using openssl as well .

From keyPair.getPrivate() on the client.key I get the privateKey ; when I do :

```
     keyStore.setKeyEntry("alias",privateKey,passphrase,chain-trust);
```

I get :

```
    java.security.KeyStoreException: BCFKS KeyStore exception storing 
    private key: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RSA keys do not 
    have the same modulus
```

what's the cause ..and how to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

this article took me to the solution :

```
    https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO16899.html
```

to save a client.key in a key store , using :

keyStore.setKeyEntry("alias",Key key, Char[] password,Certificate[] chain);

the key is the private portion of the client.key,

the Certificate[] chain SHOULD be the (client.crt+intermediate.crt+root.crt) ,concatenated all together.

Mistakenly I was using only the (intermediate.crt+ root.crt)   concatenated together.